# Como pegar o valor máximo/mínimo de um inteiro na linguagem C

Tags: c, c++

Fala pessoal!
Existe alguma função na linguagem C que pega o valor máximo/mínimo de um inteiro?

Comment: Por "valor máximo de um inteiro" você diz o maior número que pode ser representado em um inteiro?

Comment: Eu também entendi que você quer o menor e maior valores possíveis de serem representados. Mas concordo com que você podia ter deixado um pouco mais claro (pra não confundir com o menor/maior valor dentre dois inteiros).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe função, mas existem macros definidas no cabeçalho [`limits.h`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) da *standard library* do C. Exemplo de código que imprime os valores mínimos e máximos de um inteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {

   printf("Menor valor de um inteiro: %d\n", INT_MIN);
   printf("Maior valor de um inteiro: %d\n", INT_MAX);

   return(0);
}
```

Veja rodando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/tVDucX).

Comment: Valeu mestre! Funcionou perfeitamente!